# Is it possible to pass lambda to Intent?

Tags: android, serialization, lambda, kotlin

I was wondering if it would be possible to pass a lambda to Intent in kotlin, since lambdas are Serializable, but with this code I am getting error when creating a PendingIntent.

```
val bundle = bundleOf(ACTION to { pause() })
val playButtonIntent = Intent(this, MusicService::class.java).apply {
        putExtras(bundle)
}
val pendingPlayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, playButtonIntent, 0)
```

error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object
```

Comment: They are @Pawel, that isn't the issue on its own.

Comment: I've created a wrapper TrackedReference<Any> that is parcelable and serializable without requiring marshaling for the underlying type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64944753/3405387

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Lambda itself is serializable.  But in your case, it closes on a variable `bundle` of some type that likely is not serializable.  So it is making a Lambda class that includes a member to hold that closed variable.  You cannot make a serializable object that contains things inside it that break serialization.

So you need to find a way not to hold that bundle class, or need to make it serializable.

See this other question in SO for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870902/3679676